# How can Android Device Manager (ADM) help to locate Android phone if Google account's password has been changed?

Tags: google-account, password, lost-phone, device-administrator

I lost my Samsung Android phone. It was connected with Google account, but I changed my Google account password. Now I am not able to trace it through Android Device Manager (ADM). When I tried, it shows

> No active devices
>
> Before you can use Android Device Manager, you must have an active Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate ADM with device administrators in the phone? If you do so, you could lock your device and no need to change the password.

But if someone is using your phone, they can reset your mobile with recovery mode. If they do so, you can't locate your mobile.

I think you should inform the police and they will looking for your mobile with the IMEI number of your mobile.

Comment: Yes, I already lodge a complaint in police station, and changed the gmail password. I was not knowing about ADM features and all. That person was using my whatsapp and sending unwanted images to my contacts, to stop that I have take another sim of same number and activated what'sapp. he is still using my phone without sim.

Comment: Oh..that is bad. I think your only solution is to wait for the police procedure.

Comment: @Rachmi In the future, install a more aggressive anti theft program into your device. I'm currently using avast anti theft which lets you silently track the device and take pictures remotely without someone ever being able to tell. And of course, erase all data and locking. I'm not advocating a singular app however. They all do a very good job.